# Fatal error: Cannot declare class WP_User_Request, because the name is already in use?

Tags: errors, fatal-error

Suddenly I am getting the following error on my website, I don't know why, 
these are the following errors shown on my website:

> 1)Fatal error: Cannot declare class WP_User_Request, because the name
>   is already in use in
>   /home/hnukt37ls4nt/public_html/wp-includes/user.php on line 3657
>
> 2)Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   wp_kses_normalize_entities() in
>   /home/hnukt37ls4nt/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php:4316 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /home/hnukt37ls4nt/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(190):
>   esc_url('https://wordpre...') #1
>   /home/hnukt37ls4nt/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(147):
>   WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_default_error_template(Array, false)
>    #2 /home/hnukt37ls4nt/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(52):
>   WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template(Array, false) #3
>   [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #4 {main} thrown
>   in /home/hnukt37ls4nt/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line
>   4316

Please help me in solving this error,

Thanks in advance.
Cheers!!

Comment: This seems like a failed update. I suggest trying a manual update to make sure WordPress is all in order: https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update

Comment: Thanks for the update Jacob.
will update it manually and let you know.

Answer (score -1):

1. Just put your class in a if condition.

```php
if( !class_exists( 'class_name' ) ) {
     class class_name {
         //....
     }
     $object = new class_name();
}
```

This will work fine for first condition

Comment: WP_User_Request is a WordPress core class though, not one OP has added.